# Ubuntu 21.04 reboots itself, sometimes hibernates

Tags: kernel, dell, hibernate, reboot, acpi

So, I've been having this problem for a while, since 18.04 I guess. My computer reboots out of nowhere. It is really, really random. The only thing I've noticed is that it only happens when my CPUs are idle, it never happened while I was working on something or playing. Also, sometimes it doesn't reboot, but my screen goes entirely black and it never comes back, so I have to force the shutdown by pressing the button down. I've read many posts on that issue, but nothing worked. My system is:

-- Dell Inspiron 5675;

-- Kernel Version: 5.11.0-25-generic;

-- Graphics Platform: X11;

-- Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 7 1700X Eight-Core Processor (64 bit);

-- Memory: 7,7 GiB of RAM;

-- Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon ™ RX 470 Graphics

Also, I'm using KDE Plasma as the desktop environment:

-- KDE Plasma Version: 5.21.5;

-- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.80.0;

-- Qt Version: 5.15.2

What system log would be more helpful? I've run the command *journalctl* and found some ACPI error messages there. Anyways, thanks in advance. Any necessary information, I'll be more than happy to provide!

Comment: Power button to shutdown?  Are you saying SysRq commands direct to kernel did not allow a safe shutdown?  ie. kernel has panic'd? or is that you haven't tried to safely shutdown?  You likewise don't mention not being able to switch to a text terminal and cleanly shutdown (though if video lockup - that wouldn't work unlike SysRq commands which go direct to kernel - but again that's useful advice).

Comment: First of all, thank you for spending some time to answer my question. So, I've been experiencing two different problems that I'm not sure whether they're related or not. Sometimes Ubuntu will simply reboot out of nowhere. It's completely random. Sometimes, however, my screen goes black and absolutely nothing works, at all. I can't switch to a terminal. Also, I've tried pressing the power off button and waiting to see what happens, but that didn't work either. I know taking a look at my system logs could help, just need to know which one!

Comment: From your description, I'd at first be thinking hardware.  To try and confirm my suspicion I'd likely use the box with a different *live* system for a day, (by different I'd opt for a different stack, maybe even a non-Ubuntu system (but avoid Ubuntu based).  As for logs; `dmesg` is where I'd explore first if the system is still running; it only shows messages for the current boot;  systemd logs (as you mentioned) for prior session(s) assuming you cleanly shutdown, but I'd try switching to terminal & use SysRq commands as per first comment as power-button tells you nothing; just looses info

Comment: I've considered this possibility. I think I'll install Windows 10 and see if the problem persists. Thank you very much!

Comment: I was suggesting a *live* system run from thumb-drive; not actually installed (it's what I'd do; thus why I suggested it). If you start with a different system and don't have the issue, you can then do the same again with another 3rd system etc gaining detail - all without touching your existing install. Then with more data - you can narrow down to what is different. GNU/linux is built from packages upstream; Ubuntu chooses specific packages at set times, Debian, Fedora, OpenSuSE etc likewise like packages but different times thus rarely align allowing great comparisons without an install

Comment: Yes, I understood that! I just thought about it and decided to use some of the spare space I have on my disk to try a different system. I tried Debian already (it didn't work), and now I'm using Manjaro. So far so good. If the problem persists, then I'll try Windows 10. Thank you!